# How to get data from a dynamic form in Angular-Meteor?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I would like to get data from a very simple dynamic form and I need your help. My basic form (which will be upgraded when I get this working) looks like this.

**HTML:**

```
<form class="new-task">

    <li ng-repeat="user in party.invited">

        {{user.email}}: <input ng-model="newTask">

    </li>

    <button ng-click="addTask(newTask);">ADD</button>
</form>
```

Basically it creates an input field for every user in my selected party. Now I would like to get all of the data in all of those input fields. Here's where I'm lost...

I tried logging stuff in the console but I always get 'undefined'.

**JS:**

```
angular.module("testapp").controller("TaskCtrl", ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$meteor',

  function ($scope, $stateParams, $meteor) {

    $scope.party = $meteor.object(Parties,$stateParams.partyId).subscribe('parties');   

    $scope.addTask = function (newTask) {
        console.log(newTask);
    };

}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood your question, you want to bind several input fields to a separate array. If this is the case, you need to create an empty array in scope and then reference array elements inside the `ng-repeat` directive in your `ng-model` attributes with `tasks[$index]`. In this way you will be able to retrieve all inputs by accessing the `tasks` array. Since you want to access all array elements at once, you don't need to pass a `newTask` argument to your `addTask` function.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.party = {
    "invited": [{
      "email": "a@mail.com"
    }, {
      "email": "b@mail.com"
    }]
  };
  $scope.tasks = [];
  $scope.addTask = function() {
    console.log($scope.tasks);
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <form class="new-task">
      <li ng-repeat="user in party.invited">
        {{user.email}}:
        <input ng-model="tasks[$index]" />
      </li>
      <button ng-click="addTask()">ADD</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hello Matthias. That worked like a charm. I tried so many things when I simply had to declare a new array. Thank you very much!